# My calls keep randomly go through Google Voice

Tags: iphone

So, only sometimes when I call a number, it will reroute me to Google Voice. I don't have the app installed.

Answer (score 1):

Does your phone reroute your calls to Google Voice, or do your calls get rerouted on the recipient end?

I think you’ll be better off seeking help on this on Google forums, as it seems to be a Google issue (with your network), not an Apple issue (with your phone).
https://support.google.com/voice/answer/165221?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: I think it's just on my end.